# Error loading pentaho cube using saiku

Tags: pentaho, saiku

Saiku plugin 2.5 for Pentaho 4.8, windows 7 , oracle 10g.

When starting the Saiku analytics view i'm getting this error:

```
name:puc1
driver:mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver
url:jdbc:mondrian:Provider=mondrian; DataSource=haki;Catalog=solution:admin/resources/metadata/puc1.mondrian.xml
mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Internal error: Error while loading plugin class 'org.saiku.plugin.PentahoDataSourceResolver'
```

My oracle db instance / name is `haki`, the connection i created in the pac named `haki` as well. the cube works on the analytics view but not showing in the saiku anlytics.

this is the file located in `admin/resources/metadata/puc1.mondrian.xml` :

```
type=OLAP 
name=haki
driver=mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver
location=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:haki;Catalog=C:\Pentaho\biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\Haki\puc1.mondrian.xml;JdbcDrivers=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
username=pentaho
password=pentaho
```

this is my schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Schema name="puc1">
  <Dimension name="DEPT">
    <Hierarchy name="DEPTNO" hasAll="true" primaryKey="DEPTNO">
      <Table name="&quot;DEPT&quot;" schema="&quot;SCOTT&quot;"/>
      <Level name="DEPTNO" column="DEPTNO" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="DNAME" hasAll="true" primaryKey="DEPTNO">
      <Table name="&quot;DEPT&quot;" schema="&quot;SCOTT&quot;"/>
      <Level name="DNAME" column="DNAME" type="String" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="LOC" hasAll="true" primaryKey="DEPTNO">
      <Table name="&quot;DEPT&quot;" schema="&quot;SCOTT&quot;"/>
      <Level name="LOC" column="LOC" type="String" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
  <Cube name="puc1">
    <Table name="&quot;EMP&quot;" schema="&quot;SCOTT&quot;"/>
    <DimensionUsage name="DEPT" source="DEPT" foreignKey="DEPTNO"/>
    <Measure name="COMM" column="COMM" aggregator="sum" formatString="#"/>
    <Measure name="DEPTNO" column="DEPTNO" aggregator="sum" formatString="#"/>
    <Measure name="EMPNO" column="EMPNO" aggregator="sum" formatString="#"/>
    <Measure name="MGR" column="MGR" aggregator="sum" formatString="#"/>
    <Measure name="SAL" column="SAL" aggregator="sum" formatString="#"/>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

I would appreciate any help.

full dump

```
12:28:35,139 DEBUG [AbstractSpringPentahoObjectFactory] Got an instance of [ISolutionRepository]: org.pentaho.platform.repository.solution.dbbased.DbBasedSolutionRepository@48d8fe
name:puc1
driver:mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver
url:jdbc:mondrian:Provider=mondrian; DataSource=haki;Catalog=solution:admin/resources/metadata/puc1.mondrian.xml
mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Internal error: Error while loading plugin class 'org.saiku.plugin.PentahoDataSourceResolver'
        at mondrian.resource.MondrianResource$_Def0.ex(MondrianResource.java:967)
        at mondrian.olap.Util.newInternal(Util.java:2400)
        at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection.getDataSourceResolver(RolapConnection.java:480)
        at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection.createDataSource(RolapConnection.java:426)
        at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection.<init>(RolapConnection.java:134)
        at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection.<init>(RolapConnection.java:90)
        at mondrian.olap.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:112)
        at mondrian.olap.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:68)
        at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jConnection.<init>(MondrianOlap4jConnection.java:140)
        at mondrian.olap4j.FactoryJdbc4Plus$AbstractConnection.<init>(FactoryJdbc4Plus.java:323)
        at mondrian.olap4j.FactoryJdbc41Impl$MondrianOlap4jConnectionJdbc41.<init>(FactoryJdbc41Impl.java:118)
        at mondrian.olap4j.FactoryJdbc41Impl.newConnection(FactoryJdbc41Impl.java:32)
        at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver.connect(MondrianOlap4jDriver.java:132)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at org.saiku.datasources.connection.SaikuOlapConnection.connect(SaikuOlapConnection.java:75)
        at org.saiku.datasources.connection.SaikuOlapConnection.connect(SaikuOlapConnection.java:46)
        at org.saiku.datasources.connection.SaikuConnectionFactory.getConnection(SaikuConnectionFactory.java:29)
        at org.saiku.plugin.PentahoSecurityAwareConnectionManager.connect(PentahoSecurityAwareConnectionManager.java:181)
        at org.saiku.plugin.PentahoSecurityAwareConnectionManager.getInternalConnection(PentahoSecurityAwareConnectionManager.java:72)
        at org.saiku.plugin.PentahoSecurityAwareConnectionManager.refreshInternalConnection(PentahoSecurityAwareConnectionManager.java:114)
        at org.saiku.datasources.connection.AbstractConnectionManager.refreshConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:112)
        at org.saiku.datasources.connection.AbstractConnectionManager.refreshAllConnections(AbstractConnectionManager.java:105)
        at org.saiku.service.olap.OlapDiscoverService.refreshAllConnections(OlapDiscoverService.java:77)
        at org.saiku.web.rest.resources.OlapDiscoverResource.refreshConnections(OlapDiscoverResource.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.jersey.EnunciateJerseyServletContainer.service(EnunciateJerseyServletContainer.java:248)
        at org.saiku.plugin.EnunciateJerseyPluginServlet.service(EnunciateJerseyPluginServlet.java:91)
        at org.saiku.plugin.ServletAdapterContentGenerator.createSaikuContent(ServletAdapterContentGenerator.java:207)
        at org.saiku.plugin.ServletAdapterContentGenerator.createContent(ServletAdapterContentGenerator.java:91)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet.doGet(GenericServlet.java:261)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoWebContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoWebContextFilter.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoRequestContextFilter.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.SecurityStartupFilter.doFilter(SecurityStartupFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:169)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.java:134)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SystemStatusFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.saiku.plugin.PentahoDataSourceResolver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection.getDataSourceResolver(RolapConnection.java:471)
        ... 107 more
```

Comment: you added saiku analytics pluggin into BI server?

Comment: Yes. I followed the exact instructions in the README file. I deleted the 6 DLL's from lib and copied the saiku pulg-in dll to WEB-INF.